# mysql exit sp with if

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures, exit

in the msql sp below i am trying to exit if the day of the week is friday but i cant get it working because there seams to be a syntax error at "END IF;" i just can't see it.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `bookFreeDay`()
    proc_label:BEGIN

  DECLARE bDone INT;
  DECLARE t1 VARCHAR(5);

  -- todo exclude sa/so
  IF DAYOFWEEK(SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)) = 5 THEN
      LEAVE proc_label;
  END IF;

  DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR select durTime from freeDays where
    (year is not null && year= substring(CURDATE(),1,4) && start=substring(SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1), 6,5))
    || (year is null && start=substring(SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1), 6,5));

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

  OPEN curs;

  SET bDone = 0;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curs INTO t1;

        select CONCAT(SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1), " 08:00:00") into @st;
        select addtime(@st, t1) into @en;

       insert into timeEntries
         (select
           null,
           idUsers,
           @st,
           @en,
           null,
           2
         from users
         where right(pensum,1)='%');

  UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

  CLOSE curs;

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [14.6.6.2 Cursor DECLARE
>   Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-cursor.html)
>
> ...
>
> Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations and
>   after variable and condition declarations.
>
> ...

```sql
...

/*
-- todo exclude sa/so
IF DAYOFWEEK(SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)) = 5 THEN
  LEAVE proc_label;
END IF;
*/

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR select durTime
                        from freeDays
                        where (year is not null &&
                               year= substring(CURDATE(),1,4) &&
                               start=substring(SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1), 6,5)) ||
                              (year is null &&
                               start=substring(SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1), 6,5));

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

-- todo exclude sa/so
IF DAYOFWEEK(SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)) = 5 THEN
  LEAVE proc_label;
END IF;

...
```